# onStartJob() never called in a scheduled job

Tags: android

Who of you can tell me why `onStartJob()` in this scheduled job is never called?

I'm testing on O-MR1. I see the logging from the `onServiceConnected()` call when the service binds, but I never see the logging from `onStartJob()`.

Here's the job:

```
public class LogUploadJobService extends JobService {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private BikeTrackerService service;

    private JobParameters jobParameters;

    ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder serviceBinder) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance.
            BikeTrackerService.BikeTrackerServiceBinder binder = (BikeTrackerService.BikeTrackerServiceBinder)serviceBinder;
            service = binder.getService();

            Logg.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected() We're bound, BikeTrackerService is now available to the LogUploadJobService.");

            // We can now start getting other callbacks.
            onServiceBound();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Logg.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected()");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Logg.d(TAG, "onCreate() " + this.hashCode());

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        Logg.d(TAG, "onStartJob()");

        jobParameters = params;

        // Now bind to the service, whether or not it's already running. Calls back to onServiceBound() below. This should never
        // create a new instance, despite using BIND_AUTO_CREATE.
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BikeTrackerService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // Return true as there's more work to be done with this job.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Logg.d(TAG, "onStopJob()");

        // Return false to drop the job.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Logg.d(TAG, "onDestroy() " + this.hashCode());

        super.onDestroy();

        // Unbind from service if bound.
        if (service == null) {
            return;
        }

        Logg.d(TAG, "Unbinding from service.");
        unbindService(connection);
    }

    private void onServiceBound() {
        FileLogger fileLogger = FileLogger.getInstance();
        String log = fileLogger.getLog();

        // The service will now put this log into the Firebase database.
        service.addAppLog(log);

        // We're done and we don't need a reschedule.
        jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
    }

}
```

And here's how I schedule it, from the class that extends the Application:

```
private void rescheduleLogUploadJob() {
    ComponentName logUploadJob = new ComponentName(this, LogUploadJobService.class);

    // Reuse the same job ID every time, to replace any previously scheduled job.
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(SCHEDULED_JOB_ID, logUploadJob);

    // Only upload the logs when the device is charging and on an unmetered network. No need to wait for idle.
    builder.setRequiresCharging(true);
    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);

    // For minSdkVersion 23:
    // Upload, at most, every six hours, within the above constraints.
    // builder.setPeriodic(INTERVAL_6_HOURS_IN_MILLIS);

    // Upload, at most, every six hours and at worst, every 12 hours, within the above constraints.
    builder.setPeriodic(INTERVAL_6_HOURS_IN_MILLIS, INTERVAL_6_HOURS_IN_MILLIS);

    // Persist the schedule across device reboots.
    builder.setPersisted(true);

    // Schedule job.
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    if (scheduler == null) {
        Logg.e(TAG, "No scheduler. Can't schedule log upload job.");

        return;
    }

    Logg.d(TAG, "(Re)scheduling log upload job");

    scheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

(Don't mind the `Logg` class, btw. It's just a wrapper around `android.util.Log`.)

[Edit]

I'm also seeing this in the logs:

```
SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I do not know how can you see logs from onServiceConnected but not from onStartJob, as you bind in onStartJob. Have you tried to stop with a debugger on the bindService line?

Comment: Good point! And in fact, I spoke too soon, because I've just seen it work after a reboot. Perhaps adb was just being flakey. I can try with the debugger attached, but won't be able to move my phone for 6 to 12 hours while the job comes round.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/libcutils/sched_policy.cpp#L341) the place, where the log is printed. No aware about the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. `onStartJob()` was being called, but my filtering of the logcat was preventing me seeing that.

Whether the `set_timerslack_ns write failed` thing is of any concern, I'm still not sure, so will accept any answer that addresses that.